# How to filter array of objects by another array of objects by property using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, object

I have two nested array of objects, how to compare two array of objects by

`id` from arrobj1 and `assignId` from arrobj2 using javascript

So, I would to know how to compare array of objects by id and assignId and return array of objects using javascript

```
Tried

const result =  arrobj1.filter(arr1 => {
       arrobj2.find(arr2 => arr2.assignId === arr1.id)
    });

var arrobj1 =[
 {id: 1, name: 'xxx', value:100},
 {id: 2, name: 'yyy', value:200},
 {id: 3, name: 'zzz', value:400}
]

var arrobj2 =[
 {country: 'IN', name: 'lina', assignId:2},
 {country: 'MY', name: 'john', assignId:3},
 {country: 'SG', name: 'peter', assignId:6}
]
```

```
Expected Code:

[
 {id: 2, name: 'yyy', value:200},
 {id: 3, name: 'zzz', value:400}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost correct, but you need to return in your filter, either by explicitly adding the `return` keyword or by removing the braces to use the arrow function's implicit return:

```
const result = arrobj1.filter(arr1 =>
  arrobj2.find(arr2 => arr2.assignId === arr1.id)
)
// or
const result = arrobj1.filter(arr1 => {
  return arrobj2.find(arr2 => arr2.assignId === arr1.id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can combine `Array.filter()` and `Array.some()` to make it more simple

```
let result = arrobj1.filter(a1 => arrobj2.some(a2 => a2.assignId === a1.id) )
console.log(result)
```

For your code,the reason is that you have missing `return` when invoke `find`

```js
var arrobj1 =[
 {id: 1, name: 'xxx', value:100},
 {id: 2, name: 'yyy', value:200},
 {id: 3, name: 'zzz', value:400}
]

var arrobj2 =[
 {country: 'IN', name: 'lina', assignId:2},
 {country: 'MY', name: 'john', assignId:3},
 {country: 'SG', name: 'peter', assignId:6}
]

let result = arrobj1.filter(a1 => arrobj2.some(a2 => a2.assignId === a1.id) )
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generally go with the `filter` and `some` combination as @flyingfox mentioned in the answer, But if you'd have thousands of records then your time complexity would increase which you can solve by removing the nested `some` loop.

So more performant code would look like the following for a bigger data set.

And yes, Either use return with braces or simply remove the braces for one-liner returns!

```js
var arrobj1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'xxx', value: 100 },
    { id: 2, name: 'yyy', value: 200 },
    { id: 3, name: 'zzz', value: 400 },
]

var arrobj2 = [
    { country: 'IN', name: 'lina', assignId: 2 },
    { country: 'MY', name: 'john', assignId: 3 },
    { country: 'SG', name: 'peter', assignId: 6 },
]

var obj = {}
for (const elem of arrobj2) {
    obj[elem.assignId] = true
}

let result = arrobj1.filter((a1) => obj[a1.id])
console.log(result)
```